# ImageView doesn't center on ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout, android-image

I can't move the image more to the left side no matter what I'm doing. It should be nicely centered but it's not...
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVJNm.png)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/turn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chain your view to two points using start/end constraints, it stays in the center of those constraints by default. But have the ability to shift it's position toward end or start the layout attribute responsible for this is `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias`
As @Robert mentioned, you can remove that attribute or set it to 0.5

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/back3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/turn"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Also I suggest you to use `AppCompatImageView` instead

Answer (score 2):

If the parent view is wider than the image, you need to add this to ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or some other appropriate value for the attribute.